# Swig: SWIG_NewPointerObj and Typemaps

Tags: c++, swig

I'm working on a Qt-Application and I use Swig to generate Python Bindings for my Public API.

I trying to implement signal/slots in SWIG and also embedding python into my final app. In the end it always boils down to a simple function, which SWIG seems to miss or I haven't found yet:

`PyObject* createPyObject(QString typeName, bool passOwnership, void* obj)`

### Requirements

The function should create a PyObject from the passed `obj`. Whereas `typeName` is the type of the instance to which `obj` points to and `passOwnership` specifies whether or not the object should be owned by the Python Interpreter afterwards. The function should:

1. Apply the **out**-Typemap for the passed type, if it exists
2. Otherwise wrap the object as a "Swig Proxy Object of Type ..." if possible
3. And if that's also not possible it should return a "Swig Object of Type ..."

### Example

Let's say I have three classes:

- `class A1` for which I have a **out**-Typemap to convert from instances of this class to  *Python-Integers*.
- `class A2` for which I have a **out**-Typemap to convert from instances of this class to *Python-Tuples*.
- `class B` which I have wrapped using a SWIG Interface file
- `class C` which is completely unknown to SWIG.

then the `createPyObject` should

- return a `PyIntObject*` if it's invoked like `createPyObj("A1",true,new A1())`
- return a `PyTupleObject*` if it's invoked like `createPyObj("A2",true,new A2())`
- return a `proxy of <Swig Object of Type 'B*'>` if it's invoked like `createPyObj("B",true,new B())`
- return a `Swig Object of Type 'C*'` if it's invoked like `createPyObj("C",true,new C())`

So to summarize: 
I want the returned PyObject to be constructed like as if it was a return value of a function which was wrapped using a SWIG interface file.

### My current implementation

```
PyObject* createPyObject(QString typeName, bool passOwnership, void* obj) {

    typeName += " *"; //Pointer symbol
    swig_type_info* info = SWIG_TypeQuery(typeName.toStdString().c_str());

    if (info == nullptr) return nullptr;

    return SWIG_NewPointerObj(obj, info, passOwnership ? SWIG_POINTER_OWN : 0);
}
```

This works fine for types which require no typemap and are known to SWIG (Point 2 in the Requirements). But it doesn't work for types which require a typemap.

**Could you provide me with a correct implementation of  `createPyObject` ?** By correct I mean, one that meets all the requirements listed above.

Comment: Can you flesh out your example to be a MCVE please? I'm not quite sure what's not working for you.

Comment: @Flexo I restructured the question. If it's still unclear to you, please point out exactly which aspects are unclear to you.

Comment: Convert between Python-Integers and instances of that class. Do you want to keep a list of live instances of a given class? This sort of contradicts the whole point of SWIG. What would make sense was to copy the functionality of SWIG_NewPointerObj and the SWIG_init and operate on some dynamic type information.

Comment: Oopps, I guess I was a bit unclear. If there's an **out**-Typemap available for the passed `typeName` it should be applied (one way). I don't need to convert it back. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Okay. SWIG_NewPointerObj uses the info to find the correct typemap and this includes the ones that you have made yourself. What I usually do is to shared typemaps between multiple libraries - shared objects. This is discussed under advanced topics in the SWIG user guide. It is pretty cool, when you have multiple libraries interfacing each other.